Next-auth authorizes me with another account
I'm using next-auth with two providers, Prisma adapter and MongoDB. At some point, the library started behaving strangely - when authorizing, it logs me in from a different account. The problem remains when using a different provider, a different browser and even a different device. For example, when I log in through my Yandex provider, it still logs me in through my Google account.
Here's what my authOptions look like:
adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
    session: {
        strategy: "jwt"
    },
    pages: {
        signIn: "/login",
    },
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: loadCreds().clientId,
            clientSecret: loadCreds().clientSecret,
            authorization: {
                params: {
                    prompt: "consent",
                    access_type: "offline",
                    response_type: "code"
                }
            }
        }),
        YandexProvider({
            clientId: process.env.YANDEX_CLIENT_ID as string,
            clientSecret: process.env.YANDEX_CLIENT_SECRET as string
          })
    ],
callbacks: {
        async jwt({ token, user }) {
            if (user) {
                const candidate = await prisma.user.findFirst({ where: { id: token.id as string } })

                if (!candidate) {
                    token.id = user!.id
                    return token
                } else {
                    return {
                        id: candidate.id,
                        name: candidate.name,
                        email: candidate.email,
                        image: candidate.image
                    }
                }
            } else {
                return token
            }
        },
        async session({ session, token }) {
            session.user!.name = token.name
            session.user!.email = token.email
            session.user!.image = token.image as string

            return session
        },
        redirect() {
            return "/"
        }
    }

I've tried clearing cache and cookies in my browsers, deleting the .next folder, checking the documentation, and still can't figure out where I made a mistake.

Take a look at your user in the database. In the default setup with a DB adapter, the first sign in will create an Account with the name of the oauth provider value in the provider field.
provider

  provider: string;

  Provider’s id for this account. Eg.: “google”

The next time you sign in, it looks up the matching Account in the database which includes that provider field.
Clearing cache/cookies or switching devices/browsers didn't change the behavior because it doesn't affect what's stored in the DB.

There's not an easy workaround that I'm aware of, unfortunately. And it depends on some further details. But maybe I can joggle some revelation by throwing out some ideas:
You can update the schema to store multiple providers and add the logic to add and check for the right provider
or create multiple accounts and link them
or add in a step to update the provider field as necessary before next-auth
if you're referring to clicking a button that says login with "provider 1" but it's redirecting you to the login screen of "provider 2" you could add a conditional to go to the provider specified by the button rather than letting next-auth redirect to the provider found on the Account
You might also look into creating a "custom" adapter by modifying the Prisma adapter and using the linkAccount fn for you use case.
https://authjs.dev/reference/core/adapters#linkaccount
This introduces opportunities for vulnerabilities if you're not careful, though, so double and triple check if you go down this route!
Again, none of them are great or easy solutions, but hopefully this provides you a path to getting unstuck (until the next issue )!
Good luck!
https://authjs.dev/reference/core/types#provider
https://authjs.dev/concepts/database-models
